# Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 300 The data types date and int are incompatible in the modulo operator

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    st.SupplyID, 
    FORMAT(SupplyTrDate, 'MMM dd, yyyy') AS 'Supply Date',
    COUNT(SDQuantity) AS 'Total Item Purchased', 
    SUM(itemsSupply_price) AS 'Total Expense'
FROM
    SupplyTransaction st
JOIN
    SupplyTransDetail std ON st.SupplyID = std.SupplyID
JOIN 
    items i ON std.itemsID = i.itemsID
WHERE 
    SupplyTrDate % 2 = 0 
    AND itemsName LIKE '%A%' OR itemsName LIKE '%a%'
GROUP BY 
    st.SupplyID, st.SupplyTrDate, SDQuantity, itemsSupply_price, SDQuantity
HAVING 
    SupplyTrDate IS NOT NULL;
```

I get an error when running this query:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 300
>   The data types date and int are incompatible in the modulo operator

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please actually [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), don't just dump a query and an error message here and expect someone to help.

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` and what do you want to achieve with `SupplyTrDate % 2 = 0`?

Comment: Also please only tag the RDBMS you are using, either MySQL or SQL Server - not both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do here - but you just cannot "divide a date by 2" - or can you tell me what March 27, 2019 divided by 2 is supposed to be??

I'm just **guessing** here - but if you want to check if the **DAY** (as a number) is an "even" day - then you'd need to apply the `DAY()` function to your date to make that check:

```
WHERE 
    DAY(SupplyTrDate) % 2 = 0
```

Also: since you're not working with an aggregated column, the condition `SupplyTrDate IS NOT NULL` should really be part of the `WHERE` clause - not the `HAVING`